# PHP SQL query for WHERE {column} IS NOT NULL returns rows with null in column

Tags: php, sql

I am running this query:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $pid WHERE ff IS NOT NULL ORDER BY time_out");
```

I am getting a response with some rows that are null in the ff column.

I verified this later on in the code with:

```
if ($reps[$i]['ff'] == null)
    {
    $test = "ff is null";
    } 
else 
    {
    $test = $reps[$i]['ff'];
    }
```

Not sure what I am missing here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe empty string treated as NULL

Comment: maybe, but is why I tried to test for that with "if ($reps[$i]['ff'] == null)" would that not work?

Comment: Mapping. Your query may return `''` but PHP treats it as NULL. I am not expert of PHP that is why only educated guess.

Comment: If you `print` or `var_dump` your `$reps[$i]['ff']`, what does it contain?  PHP's `null` and SQL's `NULL` are two different things.  Your check for `null` in PHP is checking to see if that array element is defined at all.  It is.  But what does that element contain?

Comment: Ah yes, I see what you saying. tried:
if ($reps[$i]['ff'] == "") 
and that did return true.

Comment: `"" == null` evaluates to `true` because it juggles types. If you really want to check for `null` use: `$reps[$i]['ff'] === null`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/80649/7362396

Comment: === null returned false. so must be an empty string then. thanks, guys. when i insert the row the ff value is from $ff = tax_test(); tax_test should be returning "return null;" does that sound ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use query

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $pid WHERE ff IS NOT NULL and $pid != '' ORDER BY time_out");
```

Comment: $pid should never be a empty string but would maybe `and ff != ''`  work?

Comment: Yes try query on sql if it worked for you. I compiled this query in my case worked.